# Understanding curtain.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, parallax

i've been trying to understand how to use the jQuery plugin curtain.js (https://github.com/victa/curtain.js).

i've tried to follow the instructions, but i must be doing something wrong because i can't get it to work.

Maybe the problem is with something else, but the jquery that i wrote is:

```
$(function () {
    $('.curtains').curtain({
        scrollSpeed: 400
    });
});
```

I've made a fiddle so you can see the code i have now.
The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NvGgW/1/

Any help would be VERY welcome.
Thank you!

Comment: you need to add curtain.js as a resource in your fiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't link to an actual copy of the plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are doing everything OK, it just doesnt work with the latest version of jquery, works ok with Jquery 1.7.2, i've changed your fiddle for you and included a copy of the plugin in the JS window:

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesking/NvGgW/3/

```
<ol class="curtains">
<li id="One" class="sectionOne">
    <h1>SECTION ONE</h1>
</li><!-- end #sectionOne -->
<li id="Two" class="sectionTwo">
    <h1>SECTION TWO</h1>
</li><!-- end #sectionTwo -->
<li id="Three" class="sectionThree">
    <h1>SECTION THREE</h1>
</li><!-- end #sectionThree -->
<li id="Four" class="sectionFour">
    <h1>SECTION FOUR</h1>
</li><!-- end #sectionFour -->
</ol>
```